# How to put quick filters in codeigniter dropdowns to help filter the results quickly relating to each table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to put quick filters to my tables. So there needs to be a number of dropdowns to help filter the results quickly relating to each of my tables. How could I do it?

This is my view file:

```
<div class="row-fluid sortable">        
            <div class="box span12">
                <div class="box-header" data-original-title>
                    <div class="box-icon">
                        <a href="#" class="btn-setting"><i class="halflings-icon wrench"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn-minimize"><i class="halflings-icon chevron-up"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn-close"><i class="halflings-icon remove"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <table id="segment" class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>UNSPSC SEGMENT</th>
                              <th>Count</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>   
                      <tbody>

                      <?php foreach($dash_present_all_selected_suppliers as $v): ?>
                              <tr>      
                                    <td class="center" style="color:#0c595b;"><a href="<?php  echo base_url(); ?>admin/dashboard1/select_segment?segment=<?php echo $v->name;?>"><?php echo $v->name;?> </a> </td>
                                    <td class="center">70%</td> 
                            </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>            
                </div>
            </div><!--/span-->

        </div><!--/
```

and that is my controller:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('dash_match_model');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('url');

}

public function index() {
    $arr['page']='dash1';
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');

    $supplier = $this->dash_match_model->dash_present_all_suppliers($user_id);
    $arr['dash_present_all_suppliers'] = $supplier;
    $this->load->view('clients/clDashboard',$arr);

}

public function select_supplier() 
{

    $supplier_name = $this->input->get('name', TRUE);

    $supplier_id="";
    $supplier_sel = $this->dash_match_model->selected_supplier_id($supplier_name);
    foreach ($supplier_sel->result() as $row){

        $supplier_id = $row->supplier_id;
    }

    $selected_supplier = $this->dash_match_model->unspsc_matched_skus($supplier_id);
    $arr['dash_present_all_selected_suppliers'] = $selected_supplier;

    $this->load->view('clients/unspscSegment', $arr);
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, you can put the URI segments of a URL inside `base_url()` to save run and increase readability e.g. this: `<a href="<?php  echo base_url("admin/dashboard1/select_segment?segment=$v->name"><?php echo $v->name;?> </a>` becomes: `<a href="<?php echo base_url("admin/dashboard1/select_segment?segment=$v->name"); ?>"><?php echo $v->name;?></a>`

Comment: @RossWilson Thanks for your reply but how can I create quick filters as dropdowns to help filter the results quickly??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by quick filters? i.e. What are they filtering? What identifier are you using to filter them? Is everything you want to filter already on the page or will you have to get more data from the server? Is it likely that you you will end up having a large dataset? In your view you have linkss to `select_segment` but in your controller I can only see `select_supplier` are these meant to be the same or are you wanting to change these links to selects? Always try and add a little background to what your app is doing and what you want to get from it.

Comment: @RossWilson Hey, Thanks for your reply. The select_segment that I am using in the view file is used in order to keep the already selected row. Now I have used flashdata as well to keep it. what I want exactly is like this link in datatables check the filter. https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: Are you happy to use datatables for this?

Comment: @RossWilson I already tried but because of the bootstrap.css that I am using I can't add datatables css as well because my whole system change. And by adding only the specific script links as well as the script the they provide, there are no results. That's why I am trying to figure out different ways of doing that. It will eb perfect if I could use datatables.

Comment: https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap

Comment: @RossWilson I have already use these links but I had not results. I just had a simple table and the quich filters are presenting but when you typing on them it is not working.

Comment: Were you including the normal datatables.js file as well? I only ask because I use dataTables and Bootstrap in quite a few of my projects.

Comment: @RossWilson these are all the js files that I included <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>    .Which one is the normal datatables.js file?

Comment: I would imagine it's the 1st one. The easiest way is to just get the most up to date version from the website. You should be loading jQuery, btw. Also, check the console in your browser for any errors.

Comment: @RossWilson i don't get any errors in my console. Actually I am getting the same simple table. It is not dataTable although I am loading all the js files and the scripts for example pagination,filtering etc.

Comment: Could you supply the code you're using to initiate dataTables on your table?